Blotter js in svelte
I'm attempting to integrate blotter.js into my Svelte project but encountering import issues. Has anyone successfully implemented blotter.js in Svelte? If so, could you share your approach and any necessary configurations or workarounds?
I've tried importing blotter.js as usual, but it doesn't seem to work properly within my Svelte components. I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly set up blotter.js in a Svelte environment.

How do you properly import and initialize blotter.js in a Svelte project?
Are there any specific modifications needed to make blotter.js compatible with Svelte's component-based architecture?
Can you provide an example of a simple chart or graph created using blotter.js within a Svelte component?
What are some common pitfalls or performance considerations when using blotter.js in a Svelte application?

If blotter.js isn't suitable for Svelte, I'd also appreciate recommendations for alternative charting libraries that integrate well with Svelte.
Any insights or experiences you can share would be greatly appreciated. Whether you've solved this issue yourself or encountered similar challenges, your input could help me overcome these integration problems and create interactive charts in my Svelte project.
